# Taking moments about an object that is hanging over an edge.

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics

**Question**: A 5000 kg bus hangs 12 m over the edge of a cliff and has 1000 kg of gold at the the front. The gold sits on a wheeled cart. A group of n people, each weighing 70 kg, stands at the other end. The bus is 20 m long.

Write down the total clockwise moment about the cliff edge in terms of n.

[A diagram is also supplied with the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1K1v.png)

The official answer to the question is Total moment = $(22 000 − 560n)g$ [Nm]   (sorry, I cannot figure out how to format this in maths text)

To make it clear what stage I am at with the question, [I have labelled the forces so far as follows.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYO7k.png) I believe you are supposed to interpret the weight of the group of people, and the weight of gold to be distributed at the very end of the bus.

My confusion arises when considering where the reaction between the bus and the cliff will lie. In the answer to the question, the reaction force is considered to be at the edge of the cliff. As a result, moments can then be taken around the edge of the cliff.

**My question:** Why is the reaction force acting at the edge of the cliff? Surely if the bus is not on the point of tilting then the reaction force would act further within the cliff.

Comment: Interesting question! What is the second part - does it ask for the strategy to retrieve the gold without causing the bus to topple over?

Comment: Yes. One person needs to walk to the end of the bus to retrieve the gold. You must find the smallest number of people needed to stop the bus falling over the cliff.

Comment: Where is the centre of mass of the bus?

Comment: It doesn't say in the question, but in the answer the weight is assumed to act in the centre.

Answer (score 1):

Moment from the bus is $5000\times2\times g=10000g(NM)$

Moment from the gold is $1000\times12\times g=12000g(NM)$

Moment from the people is $70\times8\times n\times g=560ng(Nm)$

Now, the total moment is $(22000-560n)g(NM)$

Answer (score 0):

You are summing up the moments about the edge of the cliff. The gold provides a clockwise torque of $(1000)(g)(12)$. The people provide a counterclockwise torque of $(70n)(g)(8)$.

Then for the bus, for problems like this, we assume the mass is evenly distributed across its full length. And when that is the case, you can calculate the torque as if the mass was all concentrated at its midpoint. Since the midpoint of the bus is 2 meters to the right of the point about which we are calculating the moment, we calculate this as a clockwise torque. $(5000)(g)(2)$

This gives a total clockwise torque of $(12000)g-(560n)g+(10000)g=(22000-560n)g$

Is that what you were asking?

Comment: Why would you assume the mass of the bus is evenly distributed?  That's a very dubious assumption.  At least it should be stated explicitly.

Comment: After seeing thousands of physics exercises I just assumed it from the verbiage and feel of the question (and the fact that they didn't give us a distribution) and confirmed it from the answer. You're right that we can't assume that but it looked like an elementary physics problem. That WOULD be one weird bus if it were actually evenly distributed.

Comment: I think I may have a misconception in calculating moments. If the bus is not on the point of tilting, then won't the reaction force act somewhere within the cliff.  For example https://i.stack.imgur.com/lG7D5.png. Doesn't this mean that the reaction force has to be factored in to the moments calculation?

Comment: You can calculate a moment about any point of your choosing. In this problem they asked to calculate it about the edge of the cliff. So we simply calculate each of the three moments/torques individually about that point. And from that point, the distances to the force are -8, 2, and 12 meters.

Comment: Oh, I think I understand your comment now. You have a good point. I believe we do have to assume the bus is tilting and the reaction force is at the pivot point so it creates a moment/torque of zero.

Comment: Sid's question is a valid one. The question probably assumes the bus is at tipping point.